# API working in browser but not working from angular js code displaying CORS issue

Tags: angularjs, cors, angularjs-resource

I am trying to integrate API from freshdesk, which is giving json output while using in browser. When used in angular js code, browser is showing CORS issue.

**In API service:**

```
     function getticket(api, param,isArray) {
     var request = $resource(remoteServiceNametickets + api,
        param,
        {
            authenticate: {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: isArray,
                headers: {
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization':'ocabjxpWZjsgVBzt3I:X'
                        }
            }
        });
        return request.authenticate().$promise.then(function (response) {
            if (response.status == '401') {//401 Unauthorized
                return;
            };
            return response;
        }, function (response) {
            //check for error status
        });
    }
```

**In Controller**

```
function createTicket(){
    $scope.values=apiService.getticket('helpdesk/tickets/26673.json');
}
```

Comment: what error you are getting in console?

Comment: Seems like cross domain request issue. The browser is suspending your request since it is trying to request a resource from a different domain.,

Comment: @user3921084 , how can we solve the error without knowing the exact error ? mention the error you are getting for cors then only some one can help you to solve.

Comment: Try with `JSONP` there are many example with angular